# print lists in brackets C#

Tags: c#, list

the best result I've found so far is this

```
List<int> pL = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 10 };
Console.Write("[");

for (int i = 0; i < pL.Count-1; i++)
    Console.Write("{0}, ", pL[i]);

Console.Write(pL[pL.Count-1] + "]");
```

but is there a better way, less bulky.

Comment: Look at [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join)... but... are you trying to create a json string from that array

Comment: `$"[{string.Join(", ", pL)}]"`

Comment: `Console.Write($"[{string.Join(",", pL)}]");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0) can take any enumerable (which `List<string>` is), so to concatenate all items in a list with a comma you can use

```
var result = String.Join(", ", pL);
```

You can also use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), so

```
Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", pL)}]");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can join the list and concatenate the pre and postfix

```
List<int> pL = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 10 };
var result = "[" + String.Join(", ", pL) + "]";
Console.WriteLine(result);
```